# SQL Server stored procedure insert query

Tags: c#, sql-server

In my C# code I am using :

```
public void Add(int ID)
{
    foreach (AccessoireToSell item in OrderToAdd.Accessoires)
    {
        Adder(item.Ref, item.Qte, item.SellPrice, ID);
    }
}

private void Adder(int refid,int Qtetosell,string sellprice,int ID)
{
    SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[4];

    param[0] = new SqlParameter("@AccessoireID", SqlDbType.Int);
    param[0].Value = refid;

    param[1] = new SqlParameter("@Qte", SqlDbType.Int);
    param[1].Value = Qtetosell;

    param[2] = new SqlParameter("@Price", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    param[2].Value = sellprice;

    param[3] = new SqlParameter("@ORDERID", SqlDbType.Int);
    param[3].Value = ID;

    Function.Execute(param, "AccessoiresAddOrder");
}
```

The procedure `AccessoiresAddOrder` :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AccessoiresAddOrder]
    @ORDERID int,
    @AccessoireID int,
    @Qte int,
    @Price Varchar(50)
AS
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Accessoires_OrderDetails] ([orderID], [AccessoireID],[Qte], [Price])
    VALUES (@ORDERID, @AccessoireID, @Qte, @Price)
```

I don't understand why the records get inserted 2 times in a row. For example I insert a row from the Datagridview and I get the same row twice in my SQL Server table.

Please note that I checked the `AccessoireToSell` list counts during the execution as well it say for "Count = 2" in my table I find 4 records.

Execute method :

```
public void Execute(SqlParameter[] param, string ProcName)
{
    SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand();
    Cmd.CommandText = ProcName;
    Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    if (param != null)
    {
        Cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
    }

    Cmd.Connection = Base.Connection;

    if (Base.Status() == true)
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    else
        Base.Open();
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: What does the code in `Function.Execute` look like?

Comment: That function is working well i tried to execute other insert procedure with it and it works all fine

Comment: if `Base.Status()` is true it will `ExecuteNonQuery` twice. Another case for using braces even on single line `if` statements.

Comment: Additionally, this method looks pretty leaky. You do not dispose your Command and it appears that do not close and dispose the connection in `Base`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code:-

```
if (Base.Status() == true)
    Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
else
{
     Base.Open();
     Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The difference is just add curly braces `{....}` to the `else` clause. The code without curly braces `{}` is executing the `Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` call twice.